# sql statement to display data from table in my textbox when I search it

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I Have a database called Capitals4
I have a table called Capitals
I have created 3 columns called Country, Capital, Population

I have 4 TextBox's and a button on my windows form 
When I type the name of a country which is in my database in to 1 of the TextBox's and hit the button I want it to search my database and display all information in the row for that country.

I named 1 of my TextBox's `TextBoxSearch`
This is where I will type in the name of a country. Below is the sql statement I thought was right

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Capitals WHERE Country='" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "'"

Country.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Capitals4").Rows(0).Item(1))
```

I named the 3 TextBox's that I want the data displayed in 
Country
Capital
Population
I don't know if my sql statement above is correct as you can see above because I have put a line in like

```
Country.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Capitals4").Rows(0).Item(1))
```

It simply lists whatever country is on Row0 item 1
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

```
Country.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Capitals4").Rows(0).Item(1))
```

Comment: SQL statement looks fine, the rest is how you execute that SQL query.

Comment: Yes this is were I am stuck, if the SQL statement is fine how do I get it to populate my 3 TextBox's with the data it finds?

Comment: that depends on what database system you are using (SQL server, MySQL, ms access, else). Search for tutorial to connect vb.net to your type of DBMS, there are many on Net. Follow one of them, and come back here if you have specific problem after trying :)

Comment: I have asked a specific question, I already know how to connect to a database and scroll through a database. The part I am stuck on is the question above.

Comment: I have asked a specific question, I already know how to connect to a database and scroll through a database. The part I am stuck on is the question above. I have created a button on my form with a TextBox when I enter text in to my TextBox and press the button I want the database to be searched for what ever text is in the box a display all info on that row in to my other 3 TextBoxes. I have already opened the database. I have been using the SQL statement above.

Comment: if that is the case, post some relevant codes showing how you tried to execute that query, and describe what you get with that, and what you actually expect. Can't help further without more information.